# Unable to use UI prompts

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim, pc, mouse

On Skyrim for PC, whenever a yes/no dialog pops up ("Are you sure you want to exit alchemy?"), or a dialog with just 'ok'("You learned the ___ enchantment"), I can't do anything.

I can't right click or left click on the yes or no or anything else on the screen. EDIT: It appears I can press 'y' for yes and 'n' for no, but nothing seems to work for 'OK' dialogs. I get "stuck", and there is nothing I can do. The sound still works and the hover effects for buttons still works, so the game hasn't crashed, but the game becomes unplayable.

What should I do?

- I use a mouse.
- I don't have any mods, this is a fresh install (3 hours old!)

**Things that don't help**

- Switching between windowed and fullscreen
- Toggling 'xbox 260 controller' in the settings
- Adding `iPresentInterval=0`
- Adding `bMouseAcceleration=0`
- Using Steam's Verify Game Cache

  - It found that my skyrim settings file was modified, from entering the above settings, and replaced it with the default
- Restarting the computer
- Playing the game with touchpad only and no external devices
- Playing with a different mouse
- Jimnms [interface key fix](http://www.skyrimnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=368) [(discussion thread)](http://www.thenexusforums.com/index.php?/topic/486809-unable-to-create-character-cannot-click-on-ok-to-name-chara/page__st__10)

  - It doesn't fix the problem I am having but it does tell you the proper keys to pres snow with key mapping consideration

Comment: try alt-tab to the desktop and then back in?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Skyrim does NOT like custom keyboard bindings. Especially if you changed M1.

To fix this, go into the controls and reset them to defaults, by pressing <kbd>T</kbd>.